# Eclipse Kepler CDT + MinGW: cannot get Eclipse to use GCC 4.8.1 instead of GCC 4.7.2

Tags: eclipse, gcc, c++11, mingw

I initially installed Eclipse Kepler CDT on a system with MinGW and GCC 4.7.2 already installed.  Today, I found that GCC 4.7.2 does not support `std::map::emplace` and that I had to upgrade to GCC 4.8.1.  I did so using the Windows 7-compatible mingw-get program.  This installed 4.8.1 alongside 4.7.2.  I could not get the Eclipse MinGW GCC toolchain to switch to the new installation.  Googling turned up nothing, and the only related questions I found on StackOverflow pertained to setting the option of "-std=c++11", which I already know to do.  I have done the following:

1. Installed GCC 4.8.1 alongside 4.7.2.  I found no option in Eclipse to force it to use the new build instead, and discovered that the GCC binary in the system path is solely for 4.7.2.
2. Uninstalled and reinstalled Eclipse Kepler CDT.  This had no effect.
3. Uninstalled MinGW and reinstalled it.  This, too, has had no effect.

The end result is that I am no closer to compiling my code, but I think I've managed to completely break my environment.

Does anyone know how to get Eclipse CDT to play nice with MinGW's GCC 4.8.1 implementation?

Comment: Try deleting "MingW" folder from your installed location, reinstall it in "C:\MingW" and restart eclipse

Comment: I found just setting your `PATH` environment so only your gcc 4.8.1 install is found should allow eclipses to use it.

Comment: @greatwolf: I no longer have 4.7.2 on my computer, and Eclipse is still trying to use it in existing and new projects instead of 4.8.1.  My PATH variable points to the MinGW root folder C:\MinGW.

Comment: @P0W: I did all that as part of the process described in my post (albeit rather ramblingly).

Comment: @gamecoder Well I use 4.8.1 with Kepler as well as Helios, I did it same way

Comment: Open up a new command prompt session and test call `g++ --version`. What does that show?

Comment: @greatwolf: g++ (GCC) 4.8.1

Comment: @jira I don't remember all the steps I tried, and I am uncertain as to what worked.  However, I remember seeing other threads that recommended starting a new workspace to reflect the new changes.  That may have been what did the trick.  I'd try looking into it more, but the hard drive on which my installation was running died  >_<